# Function returns value of a series that is ambiguious

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, dataframe

Im trying to write a function that checks if a value of a column in a dataframe is equal to a value then return the wage column for that row otherwise return np.na but i keep getting the follwing error:
 The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use `a.empty`, `a.bool()`, `a.item()`, `a.any()` or `a.all()`.

Here is my code:

```
def hourly_wage_worker(row):

    """ return np.nan if a row is not unionized and hourly wage if unionized"""

    if row['union'] == 'Union':
        return row['wage']
    else:
        return np.nan
```

Comment: by dataframe, do you mean that you are using pandas?

Comment: Yes that is what i mean

Comment: To ensure the right people are looking at your question, make sure the tags are right (e.g. include pandas) and ask the question using the [minimum, complete example guideline from](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using pandas,

Try 
General example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(-1, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
df['c'] = np.where(df['A']==0, df['B'], np.nan)
```

your case

```
df['newcolumn'] = np.where(df['union']=='Union', df['wage'], np.nan)
```